# SQL find and replace html text

Tags: html, sql, replace

I want to replace a html string with another in a SQL database. I know the main syntax, but the string has html tags.

Here is an example:

```
update wp_posts 
set post_content = replace(post_content, '<img alt="100%" id="home-img" src="/wp-content/themes/wp-theme/images/100pc.png">'
, '<a href="fblink" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a><img alt="100%" id="home-img" src="/wp-content/themes/wp-theme/images/100pc.png">'
);
```

I think I should know the correct syntax of this but I think the problem is with ", >, = characters.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What error you got after using such query?

Comment: What **concrete database** are you using? SQL is just the structured query language - but the string manipulation capabilities vary by vendor - so we really should know if you're using MySQL, Oracle, IBM DB2, SQL Server, Postgres or something else entirely. Please update your **tags** accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9dfd/5/3) that demonstrates that you are using the correct syntax.  You could also use

```
update wp_posts 
set post_content = '<a href="fblink" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a><img alt="100%" id="home-img" src="/wp-content/themes/wp-theme/images/100pc.png">'
WHERE post_content = '<img alt="100%" id="home-img" src="/wp-content/themes/wp-theme/images/100pc.png">';
```

Comment: What if he want to replace only part of `post_content` value?

Comment: Then his replace function works as demonstrated in the SQL Fiddle